# Entropy of a gas of $N$ distinguishable Particles

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

Suppose I have a container contain $N$ particles, all of which are distinguishable. How would I calculate the entropy of this gaseous system. The Hamiltonian of the system is simply the sum $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i}$ and I believe (not 100% sure) that the partition function is:

$Z = \frac{1}{h^{3N}}\int exp(-\beta H)d^3p_1...d^3p_N d^3q_1...d^3q_N = \frac{V^N}{h^{3N}}\int exp(-\beta H)d^3p_1...d^3p_N$

Is this correct so far?

Would the next logical step be to break the integral up into the product of $N$ integrals, each looking like $\int exp(-\beta \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i}) d^3p_i$, convert into spherical coordinates, and evaluate the gaussian integral?

Will this calculate the partition function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that one needs the entropy as a function of temperature ($T$), volume ($V$), and the number of particles ($N$), your starting point is *almost* correct (the reason for the *almost* will be explained at the end of this answer). For the moment, I will concentrate on formal manipulations. If one needs entropy as a function of other variables, other routes (and other ensembles) could allow getting more directly the answer.

Under such a hypothesis, the expression for $Z$ is correct. Being purely kinetic hamiltonian, the integration over the positions is trivial. Using cartesian coordinates, the integral over the $3N$ components of the momenta corresponds to a product of $3N$ gaussian integrals. There is no compelling reason to introduce spherical coordinates.

The reason I started writing that the expression of the partition function you are using is *almost* correct is related to the fact that, notwithstanding what is written in many textbooks, the partition function for a classical gas of distinguishable particles **does not** differ from the case of indistinguishable particles. If this were the case, the entropy of milk would not be extensive, and the entropy of a glass of milk would not be twice the entropy of half glass.

Unfortunately, clarification about such a point is quite recent, and I would be careful to use this result in front of an audience not aware of the current status of the discussion. The starting reference is a paper published in 2002 by Swendsen.
( Swendsen, R. H. (2002). *[Statistical mechanics of classical systems with distinguishable particles. Journal of statistical physics](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1015161825292)*, 107(5), 1143-1166 ). A more recent and updated version is [here.](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/19/11/603)

Comment: So just to be sure, I need to divide the partition function I have by $\frac{1}{N!}$, right?

Comment: @Amatuer Yes. However, notice that the factor $\frac{1}{N!}$ plays a fundamental role only when one is discussing extensiveness or when differentiating the free energy with respect to $N$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly, this will be the partition function. However, there is no need to go to spherical coordinates. Just take the integral in Cartesian coorindates:
$$
\int e^{-\beta p_i^2/(2 m_i)} = \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi m_i}{\beta}}
$$
You will have the product $3 N$ $1D$ gaussian integrals:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{N} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi m_i}{\beta}}
$$